# .NET set HttpClient sent request from one IP

Tags: .net, kestrel-http-server

I'm working on my project and I use connection to FatSecret API in my .NET 6 app, and I have a problem that my app is using IP that I'm currently connected to from the Internet Provider. The question is can I somehow set this by kestrel or anyhow to set my app IP to be sending from one IP always?

I tried to set range of IPs, like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24, on the FatSecret API page but, I believe, I cannot do this unless I'm premium user of this API and no I can't afford this only for this project.

Comment: The question shows confusion on how IP addresses and internet connections work and has nothing to do with programming, much less Kestrel. The IP is the *machine's* IP, assigned by your router or, if you use a modem, your ISP. If the API you want requires a static IP for whitelisting you'll have to *buy* a static IP from your ISP. Businesses and public web servers have static IPs (usually), which means you're trying to use an API meant for businesses. You'll have to check whether there's a different API for consumers with dynamic IPs

Comment: Why is it so important to have a static ip in the first place? As stated in the answer before, you are bound to the ip address you get from your isp. You can't fix this with kestrel or fatsecret. 

If you need a static ip in your own network you can of course fix that in the router itself. 

So what is it you actually want to achieve?

Comment: The problem is that everyday i want to connect to this API i need to add current IP in the range of IP Restrictions that is connected to my key from this API, it's just annoying that i need to do it everyday or whenever i connect do other ISP. Sorry for any mistakes i'm not familiar with how the IP is working.